# Does Urgent Mail go to the Priority Inbox?

Tags: gmail

This is a follow up to [Send Urgent Mail in Gmail](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/5965/send-urgent-mail-in-gmail)

If someone sent me mail from a client/application that sends the urgent flag, will this automatically be sent to important messages section ?

If not, is there a filter I can apply to get it to do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If someone sent me mail from a
>   client/application that sends the
>   urgent flag, will this automatically
>   be sent to important messages section
>   ?

Maybe, maybe not. It was not stated in the Gmail Help. It seems like Gmail will do it automatically based on user action (your action). Reference: [How Priority Inbox works](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=186543)

> If not, is there a filter I can apply
>   to get it to do this ?

You can create filters as usual (based on sender, subject etc) and mark the emails as important.